# Why does a hash function return a size_t, and how is it used?

Tags: c++, hashtable, hash

I understand the mathematical basis for hash tables.  I have a hash function (that I found somewhere) below:

```
/* Fowler / Noll / Vo (FNV) Hash */
static const size_t InitialFNV = 2166136261U;
static const size_t FNVMultiple = 16777619;
size_t myhash(const string &s, int length)
{
    size_t hash = InitialFNV;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        //XOR the lower 8 bits
        hash = hash ^ (s[i]);

        //Multiply by the multiple
        hash = hash * FNVMultiple;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

1. Why does this return a `size_t`?
2. How would one use this to write a
   `store()` function which places a
   string in a hash table?
3. How can this be adapted for an array
   of characters?
4. In regards to #3, would it be appropriate to replace
   the `for` loop with a `while` loop that
   terminates at the `'\0'` character?

FYI, I am studying up for a second job interview, and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Is "somewhere" in a homework problem?

Comment: I read question 1 and thought, "Great question!". After I finished question 4, the entire thing looked to me like it was homework. Is it?

Comment: It's not homework at all.  I am studying for a second job interview.  In the first interview, they asked a bit about hash tables, so I'm trying to learn more in-depth.

Comment: If `const string& s` is a `std::string`, then you dont need the `int length` parameter, as you can use `s.length()` - AND - it will already work for null terminated char arrays (as `std::string` has a constructor to handle them).

Comment: Note also that C++0x uses `size_t` as the `result_type` for `std::hash`, and hash function objects are required to return `size_t` (17.6.3.4). Not just convertible to `size_t`, *exactly* `size_t`. So, if you're going to use your hash function with standard containers in future then you have to return `size_t`, even if personally you think it would have been better for the standard to use some other integer type.

Answer (score 2):

1. It returns `size_t` because that's the native integer (also fastest). Why choose anything else?
2. "The table"? Which table? If you mean a hashtable, then you can use the return value to choose a random bucket to put the object in. (Hint: Think "remainder".)
3. Isn't it already adapted for an array?
4. If it's a null-terminated string, why not?

Comment: Gosh people, it's not homework.  I'm not even in school.  By "the table", I meant implementing a hash table.

Comment: @Adam: Ah I see; apologies for that assumptions, that's what it looked like. Slight edit to my answer.

Comment: So you're saying if I have 100 buckets, I can use a "mod 100" operation to decide what to put it in.  Yes?

Comment: @Adam: Yes; that's the most straightforward way, and probably one of the most reasonable. As long as you're consistent, you could use whatever fancy algorithm you like (doesn't have to be `mod`), but `mod` is probably just as great.

Comment: size_t is the integral type returned by sizeof, and if it's not used to refer to the size in bytes of something I'd consider it as a semantic error.

Comment: The hash function doesn't necessarily measure the size of anything, so it still doesn't make sense to me, other than for performance reasons.

Comment: I agree change `size_t` to `int`.

Comment: I always use `size_t` if I have no reason to change to `int`. For one thing, `int` is signed, and it isn't always very clear how that translates to a remainder. For another thing, why would you switch to `int` or `unsigned int`? Is there any specific reason to?

Comment: Also, another reason to use `size_t`: Because it will be used to (indirectly) index into an array, it is indeed related to the array's size.

Comment: @ceztko - There are arguments in your favour, but sometimes, names indicate an (often "canonical") example of the kind of thing they hold. A name like "size_or_subscript_or_hash_or_whatever_t" wouldn't be very practical, yet hashes, container subscripts etc will naturally take the same basic type as container sizes.

Comment: @Adam @Richard Use `size_t`. It's unsigned (modulo arithmetic is important!), and it's intended to be a reasonable yet large integer type (it measures the sizes of things, indexes arrays, etc.). It is the proper type for this application.

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't have to be `size_t`, but it should probably be an unsigned integer type so mod is well-defined.
2. The usual way is to use the hash function to transform the 'key' data into an array index. So you mod by the size of the array to get an integer from 0 to SIZE-1 that you can use as an index. You'll also need a "collision resolution strategy" because unless the hash yields perfect results, some pairs of keys which are different will hash to the same value.
3. It appears already to be so adapted.
4. If the string ends in NUL, you can search for the null. But the function as written is passed a length as argument. Simplest to leave the working function alone, and call it with the result of strlen().

Ps. the `const string &s` means C++, *not* C. This may be important when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

`string` holds it's own length, you don't need it to be passed in. That's C++, not C- no references in C. There's no need for `strlen` or anything like that, or `NULL` terminators, or anysuch. That means that replacing it with a while loop looking for `\0` would be Bad™, as there's no guarantee that `std::string` even has one, let alone has it as it's terminator.